# How to set up WSL toolchain in CLion to behave like interactive WSL?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, wsl-2

I've got a Debian WSL2 install that I'm using to write some cross platform C code. As part of the CMake setup, I'm calling a non-global install of npm (which I installed using nvm). This works fine when running interactively, but when run from the CLion Run configuration, it isn't aware of the NVM install - likely because it's not sourcing the bash_profile before running. How can I get a non-interactive shell to run interactively in this context?

Comment: If you run your bash with `-i` it behaves interactively. However, if this is **necessary** to get your install being done, I suspect that your bash startup files are badly designed, and if I were you, I would fix this instead.

Comment: The bash_profile I have is based on how nvm installs itself. I've tried using -i to no avail unfortunately

Comment: If `-i` did not work, then it is not related to the interactivity of the shell. Of course to make sure that you applied the  `-i` correctly, I suggest that you explicitly test in your shell script, whether the shell really is inteactive.  BTW, your ~/.bash_profile (like all startup files in your home directory) is hopefully based on what **you** place there, and not what some obscure installation software is writing in it. The files are under your responsibility, and you have to ensure that their content makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly find your NPM install through NVM, you can use a combination of `sudo` and `source`. The key is to always source `nvm.sh` before attempting to use anything installed by npm

### In your CMake

```
add_custom_command(
  COMMAND sudo -u <your user> /path/to/script.sh
  ...
)
```

### In your build script, /path/to/script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# other init stuff

# before your first npm/nvm call
source "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"

# now you can use anything installed by npm
```